# div hide/show after data is saved in database and page is reloaded in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

i have 4 div's and one linkbutton at footertemplate of a gridview.
clicking on flip1 it will show panel3.
when you click on linkbutton6 it takes data from footertemplate and saves data to database but when the page is reloaded it does not show div containing gridview that is div with id panel3. it will be hidden.
div with id panel3 contains gridview.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#flip1").click(function () {
                $("#panel3").slideToggle("fast");
            });
        });
</script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#panel1").hide();
            $("#panel2").hide();
            $("#panel3").hide();
            $("#panel4").hide();
        });</script>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("[id*=LinkButton6]").click(function () {
                alert("Clicked.");
                $("#panel3").show();

            });
        });
    </script>

<asp:LinkButton ValidationGroup="compempty" ID="LinkButton6" runat="server"
OnClick="LinkButton6_Click" ForeColor="Red">Add Complication</asp:LinkButton>
```

i am able to get alert message when linkbutton6 is clicked but panel3 is still hidden.
how to show div when page is reloaded...
Thanks for the help....

Comment: you use different script tag for each action, please change it

Comment: please post your html too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#flip1").click(function () {
                $("#panel3").slideToggle("fast");
              });

            $("#panel1").hide();
            $("#panel2").hide();
            $("#panel3").hide();

            $("[id*=LinkButton6]").click(function () {
                alert("Clicked.");
                $("#panel3").show();

            });
        });
    </script>
```